# HTML File in Python https server

Tags: python, html, web, https

I am a beginner and want to make a website with html, while using phyton to make the https server.

So the question is how do i integrate the html file or code to the http phyton server?

or should i use another programming language to make this?

The very basic http server i have in python:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 8080

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Request: %s</p>" % self.path, "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>This is an example web server.</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an HTML file called `index.tpl`

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>https://pythonbasics.org</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Request: {{path}}</p>
<p>This is an example web server.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Use template engine in your responding code

```py
from bottle import template

....

self.wfile.write(bytes(template('index', path=self.path), 'utf-8'))
```